# Difference between get away from and take away from

Tags: phrase-meaning, vocabulary

Please explain the difference between get ... away from ... and take ... away from ... .

For example: They get the children away from the TV. They take the rubbish away from the house.

when we use get away and when take away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To get away from ...** has several meanings (see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_away)), including "to move away from ...". Here's an example from Wiktionary:

> Get away from the edge of the cliff!

In the phrase "get the children away from the TV", get is used as a [transitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb) (i.e. it has an object: "the children"), whereas the Wiktionary example uses get in an [intransitive manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb). However, the meaning is similar. The idea is to move the children away from the television by making them do something else (e.g. play outside).

**To take [something] away (from)** is always used in a transitive manner; see the [examples in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_away). The first meaning is, "To remove something and put it in a different place." So the sentence "They take the rubbish away from the house" refers to rubbish removal.

Some examples of "take away":

- "Now dustmen won't take your rubbish away if wheelie bin is too heavy to pull with two fingers" (article title, [Daily Mail, 07.06.2008](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1024714/Now-dustmen-wont-rubbish-away-wheelie-bin-heavy-pull-fingers.html))
- "They took away his tube of wasabi at the airport and he didn't get it back." ([Independent, 18.11.2011](http://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/international/wasabi-taken-by-north-korean-customs-officers-may-have-contributed-to-japan-defeat-6264260.html))
- "What I Took Away From CXDay In London, UK" (blog post title; meaning: "what I learnt from ..."; [The Customer & Leadership Blog](https://thecustomerblog.co.uk/2014/10/08/what-i-took-away-from-cxday-in-london-uk/), 08.10.2014)

When "take away" uses people as (grammatical) object, these people are usually moved elsewhere without their consent. "They took away the children" could mean "they [=some public authority] took the children into custody" or even "they kidnapped the children". See e.g.:

- "The courts took my children away from me because I'm a working mother" (article title, [Daily Mail, 02.09.2009](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-1209243/The-courts-took-children-away-Im-working-mother.html))
- "Social services took my children" (article title, [The Telegraph, 26.02.2011](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/mother-tongue/8349748/Social-services-took-my-children.html))
- "The experience of the transatlantic slave trade took the enslaved Africans away from their roots." (a slightly different meaning than the above; [Port Cities - Bristol, no date](http://discoveringbristol.org.uk/slavery/after-slavery/wider-world/african-diaspora/identity-and-roots/))